# libav converted audio file distorted

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to implement a file converter using libav. Currently I am testing just the audio convertion (for example aac input and mp3 output). I am using the code from this question [Conversion from mp3 to aac/mp4 container (FFmpeg/c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233112/conversion-from-mp3-to-aac-mp4-container-ffmpeg-c) but the resulting output file sounds corrupted (too slow, noisy, distorted).

[image]
This is the result from converting AAC to mp3. AAC input format is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP and mp3 output format is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P. It looks like part of the one channel is inverted on the other channel?

I am using avresample to convert the audio data. I just cant find out what is wrong, i already looked through the examples but as i can see i am doing it just like in the examples.
Here is my converter class:

http://pastebin.com/c6hvrRaM (.h)

http://pastebin.com/u6iAPHZ9 (.cpp)

I know this is pretty much but I am desperated...

Comment: Even the upper channel does not look like audio. Those sudden silences are not going to happen in real data. The fact that each such silence corresponds to a burst of audio on the lower channel is **highly** suspect.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. I guess there is something wrong with the resampling or maybe even decoding the source data?

Comment: Is your input stereo?

Comment: yes, input and output is stereo

Comment: Ok I got it working now for mp3, but for example if i choose flac as output format the audio length is 0. the file got around 19 MB and there is content in it but I cant play the file.